# How to create an JSON array like this in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

What is the best way to create an array that looks like the following:

```
 [
        {
            "id":"1",
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "id":"3",
            "value": false
        },
        {
            "id":"5",
            "value": true
        },
        {
            "id":"6",
            "value": false
        },
        {
            "id":"9",
            "value": true
        },
    ]
```

My code:

```
                //add to array
                thing = {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "value" : "true"

                };

                thingArray.push(thing);
```

It does not seem to be properly formatted when I put the output in a JSON validator.

Comment: Are you actually serializing it to JSON at some point?  It looks like you're basically just working with a JavaScript object there.

Comment: I guess you want `true` instead of `"true"`. you also seem to confuse JavaScript objects with JSON.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented further up, make sure you're actually serializing it to JSON at some point.  In your code example you're simply working with a JavaScript object, which isn't the same thing as JSON.  Here's an example:

```
// start with a regular JavaScript array
var array = [];


// push some regular JavaScript objects to it
array.push({
    id: 1,
    value: true
});

array.push({
    id: 2,
    value: false
});

// serialize your JavaScript array into actual JSON
var json = JSON.stringify(array);

// do whatever you want with it...
console.log(json);
```

Here's a [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/guyitekidise/1/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Here's some more code to get you started:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({"id": 1, "value": "true"});
arr.push({"id": 2, "value": "false"});

console.dir(arr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gg014w0h/

You can run that fiddle and then check your console output. You'll see the contents of the array pretty clearly.

Answer (score 0):

JSON validators will not like the trailing comma of the array.  There is a difference between `console.log(array)` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(array))`.  You may want to use the latter.

Also note that booleans are allowed in JSON:

```
"value": "true",
"value": true
```

Those are both valid and they mean different things.